# Custom sliders for x-y values on chart. How?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, slider

everyone!
I have a problem with my iOS app(swift lang). 
I need chart with sliders and sliders must change by touch throw x-y lines, and after this I need work with x-y point of each slider.

Maybe you know some pods, or examples like this.
I hope you can help me.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Checkout: https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#charts